# JQuery QueryBuilder nested rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-builder

I've implemented a JQuery Builder in my .Net MVC 5 App, and it is working fine.
But now I want to nest some filters. What does it means?

I have two select2, lets say Category and SubCategory, the behavior I'm looking for is next:

1. If Category has included, then show in SubCategories all values corresponding to its respective Category.
2. If no Category has included, then show all SubCategories.

Here is the way my query builder looks like right now:

```js
var rules_basic = {
   condition: 'AND',
   rules: [{
     id: 'price',
     operator: 'less',
     value: 10.25
   }, {
     condition: 'OR',
     rules: [{
       id: 'category',
       operator: 'equal',
       value: 2
     }, {
       id: 'category',
       operator: 'equal',
       value: 1
     }]
   }]
 };

    $('#builder').queryBuilder({
   plugins: ['bt-tooltip-errors'],
   
   filters: [{
     id: 'category',
     label: 'Category',
     type: 'integer',
     input: 'select',
     values: {
       1: 'Category 1',
       2: 'Category 2'
     },
     operators: ['equal', 'not_equal', 'in', 'not_in', 'is_null', 'is_not_null']
   }, {
     id: 'subcategory',
     label: 'SubCategory',
     type: 'integer',
     input: 'select',
     values: {
       1: 'Subcat 1 - Cat 1',
       2: 'Subcat 2 - Cat 1',
       3: 'Subcat 3 - Cat 1',
       4: 'Subcat 4 - Cat 2',
       5: 'Subcat 5 - Cat 2',
       6: 'Subcat 6 - Cat 2'
     },
     operators: ['equal', 'not_equal', 'in', 'not_in', 'is_null', 'is_not_null']
   }],
   rules: rules_basic
 });
    /****************************************************************
          Triggers and Changers QueryBuilder
 *****************************************************************/

 $('#btn-get').on('click', function() {
   var result = $('#builder').queryBuilder('getRules');
   if (!$.isEmptyObject(result)) {
     alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
   }
   else{
    console.log("invalid object :");
   }
   console.log(result);
 });

 $('#btn-reset').on('click', function() {
   $('#builder').queryBuilder('reset');
 });

 $('#btn-set').on('click', function() {
   //$('#builder').queryBuilder('setRules', rules_basic);
   var result = $('#builder').queryBuilder('getRules');
   if (!$.isEmptyObject(result)) {
    rules_basic = result;
   }
 });

 //When rules changed :
 $('#builder').on('getRules.queryBuilder.filter', function(e) {
  //$log.info(e.value);
 });
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.query-builder/2.3.3/js/query-builder.standalone.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div id="builder"></div>
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn-set">Set Rules</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-get">Get Rules</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" id="btn-reset">Reset</button>
```

Here is my [Fiddle](http://codepen.io/facundo_larocca/pen/pRGqma)

I cant figure out how to do what I want. I've included Cat in Subcategory name just to indicate relation between them, the original structure is:

```
Category: {
    Id: Integer,
    Name: String
}

SubCategory: {
    Id: Integer,
    Name: String,
    CategoryId: Integer
}
```

Thanks.